# Order confirmation email shows wrong timezone in summer time

Tags: email, magento, timezone, dst

When I created an order,the order confirmation email showed me the wrong time.

- The order created time on order list of dashboard is correct, just shows EDT.
- The "created_at" column of "sales_flat_order" table stores the order time as UTC.
- Order email's time is "UTC+1".
- ***I do have to show the EDT time on order email.***

What's wrong?

- On the winter time, Order email showed me "UTC".
- After Mar 11,2018(on the summer time), the order email shows me the "EDT + 5" ( same with UTC+1).

Even though i changed the default timezone on Mage.php, locale.php and config.xml, the order confirmation email showed me the EDT+1 date. 
It's very wired. Is there any solution?

I already matched the server time, web server time and store timezone.

- Server timezone: EDT.
- Web server timezone: America/New_York
- magento timezone: America/New_York.

The time created in the email template {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}} 
shows us the "UTC+1". 
[image]
Hope good solution.

Comments: I debugged it on local server and live site.
When I get the time result on these codes, live site shows me the wrong time.

- $order->getCreatedAt();       Local time output - UTC,   Live output - UTC
- $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(); Local - EDT, Live - UTC+1(estimated result must be EDT as same with local server)

All sources are same because local source is a clone from live site
Live site uses the external database(RDS), but local server is not.

**\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Abstract.php**

```
/**
 * Get object created at date affected with object store timezone
 *
 * @return Zend_Date
 */
public function getCreatedAtStoreDate()
{
    return Mage::app()->getLocale()->storeDate(
        $this->getStore(),
        Varien_Date::toTimestamp($this->getCreatedAt()),
        true
    );
}
```

Comment: If this question is about writing code in Magneto, then you are in the right place but you need to show your code.  If it's not about specific code you are writing, then you are in the wrong place and need to ask on [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: All code are based on default core on Magento1.9.2.4. Also, when I debug it on my local server, the estimated result is correct. On local server, when I output this code, the results are as follow. $order->getCreatedAt(); Local- UTC/Site - UTC, $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(); Local - EDT, but Live site - UTC+1 It means the $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate() shows the wrong time on live site. What's the matter? I already checked server time and web server timezone as New_York timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue.
In the some modules, there were timezone reset code part.
It was settled as "EST".
After fixing it with UTC, the time of order email was corrected.

```
    //date_default_timezone_set('EST');
    date_default_timezone_set(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);
```

Solved successfully.